# How do I extract text after a word including underscores?

Tags: regex

I have the following words:

```
Topshop_AW19_Pro_MOB_Competitors(mid price point)custom_affinity

Topshop_AW19_Pro_MOB_Competitors(mid price point)rubbish_affinity

Topshop_AW19_Pro_MOB_friendly_stuff(mid price point)custom_affinity

Topshop_AW19_Pro_MOB_friendly_stuff(mid price point)custom_affinity234234
```

I would like to extract all text after the word `MOB` including the underscore - so this means for the first sentence i would obtain:

```
_Competitors(mid price point)custom_affinity
```

How can I match everything after the word `MOB`?

Tried using a reverse quantifier - but did not get the correct result.

Comment: Just match `MOB(_.*)$` or replace `^.*_MOB` with empty string.

Comment: This does not work - it extracts MOB - i do not want MOB - i want everything after MOB!

Comment: @anubhava I think you misunderstand me here - I do not want to grab the first captured group - I have resorted to using the \K in order to reset the match to capture all after first matched group MOB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MOB(_.*)
```

[image: Regex description]

[Sample on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CsEB64/1/)

[Sample in php](https://3v4l.org/MK5SO)

**EDIT:**

if capturing groups are not allowed:

```
MOB\K_.*
```

[image: Regex description 2]

https://regex101.com/r/CsEB64/2

Comment: I would like to not capture the MOB text at all - is this possible?

Comment: Thanks - this is the answer I needed - will look into \K in future!